# Confused about partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have a 480 GB SSD, and a 1TB HDD.
I installed my Ubuntu 18.04 on my SSD. Then I made partitions on my HDD for swap area (17 GB), `/home` (30 GB) and `/` (20 GB).

My SSD was showing "do not use this partition". I didn't understand what it meant. I went ahead for installation and I also installed my boot loader on my SSD. Now the problem arises when I try to download a 10GB file into my Downloads it says "Home is out of space only 700 MB left".

I want to know how to redo the partition without affecting my current OS or data. I also want to know how can I store my data like in Windows we have local disks. Do we have anything analogous to that on Ubuntu?

I executed this command:

```
sudo parted --list
```

[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx4DW.png)
Can someone suggest if anything is not right.
I have 16GB ram so I added swap area 17 GB

Here I have added the output for

sudo df -h

[terminal output for df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8BCT.png)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! your swap partition is way too big or only if you have more than 16GB RAM installed. Check this article https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `sudo df -h`